# Retrieving MySQL *con value in C API

Tags: mysql, c

I am trying to retrieve data from mySQL database. And I write a function to do that. But when the thread returned back to the main(), the value in con is all NULL. I don't know why. And I use Xcode to debug this.

Actually, it works fine yesterday. I just want to change my program's path, then it failed. Even though I change it back, it still doesn't work anymore. And I have wrote a small program to test the connection, it is the same problem.

Below is the small program I tried. They have the same problem.

```
#include "fun.h"

int main(void) {

MYSQL* con;
int num;
int* p_num=&num;

change_num(p_num);
printf("[%d]Hello, World!\n",num);

// After the execution, con is still NULL.
MYSQLInit(con);
if (con==NULL) {
    finish_with_error(con);
}

return 0;
}
```

The function file:

```
#include "fun.h"

void MYSQLInit(MYSQL* con){

con=mysql_init(NULL);
if (con == NULL)
    finish_with_error(con);

/* mySQL login */
if (mysql_real_connect(con, "85.235.3.37", "July", "0000",
                       NULL , 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
{
    finish_with_error(con);
}

if (mysql_query(con, "USE lamp")) {
    finish_with_error(con);
}
// con has correct value here
}

void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con)
{
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
mysql_close(con);
exit(1);
}

void change_num(int* p_num){
*p_num=10;
}
```

Comment: So in the function file, in `MYSQLInit()`, after you call `mysql_init()`, `con` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I then added `mysql_store_result( )` and `mysql_fetch_row( )` to read the data from mysql data. It works fine. Only if it return back to main, it is empty again.

Comment: What does `mysql_error(con)` tell you?

Comment: @moffeltje It was empty. It doesn't print any msg at all except `\n`. That means it is not error, just `con` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference one more level:

```
void MYSQLInit(MYSQL **con)
{
    *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    // ...
}
```

Then, to call:

```
MYSQLInit(&con);
```

Or, you could return `MYSQL *` from your function, e.g.:

```
MYSQL *MYSQLInit()
{
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    // ...
    return con;
}
```

And call like this:

```
con = MYSQLInit();
```

Comment: No, stil. Even if I return it. it is NULL in the main().

Comment: @ButterLover If `con` is not NULL before you `return` it, I don't think it's possible that it magically becomes NULL at the caller.

Comment: I can't agree with you more. And now I am trying to find out why it magically becomes NULL. I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error because of that. And as I mentioned, it works fine nearly a month. I really have no idea why it doesn't now. But, Thank you so much anyway.